# GRUB error Fedora 15 when Dual Booting on MacBook Pro

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, grub2, macintosh

I am having trouble getting Fedora 15 running on my MacBook Pro. I had Fedora 15 installed before on this MBP before, so I know it works. I basically followed the good old instructions of

1. Create a Windows partition in bootcamp (rEFIt was already installed from trying to get ubuntu running)
2. Boot from disk and install in Windows partition with bootloader on installed on the / partition
3. Install, reboot, and resync the MBR using rEFIt partitioning tool
4. Shut down the computer and start up on the parition you installed linux on

Now I get a grub error:

```
error file not found
grub rescue>
```

Another weird thing is that I have two Linux boot instances showing up in rEFIt, but that is just a rEFIt issue.

Any recommendation on what do to?

EDIT:

It seems like the error message is GRUB 2 error message and so that seems to lurking around somewhere, problem has been there since I formatted the drives. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like GRUB2 is living on sda1 and fedora on sda3, so it looks there first. Any recommendation on how to get it off?

Answer (score 0):

When using rEFIt, make sure you select the right partition where Fedora installed. You also need to confirm a few items (I'm assuming a non-gpt partition table):

1. Have you `set root='hd0,X'` inside the menuentry option of `grub2.cfg`. where `X` is the serial number of the partition mounted at `/boot`?
2. Have you updated the kernel line in `grub2.cfg`  to point to the correct `/boot` partition? You my choose to use the disk UUID like so:

   ```
   root=UUID=<your-boot-partition-uuid>
   ```

These steps require editing the `grub2.cfg` which is dangerous. I would suggest booting your MacBook using a USB key with any linux installed, then use `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2.cfg` to generate a new grub.cfg for you as reference.